# asset_path returns wrong path in production environment

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, erb

I have a css which contains this:

`font.css.erb`

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'thsarabun';
  src: url('<%= asset_data_uri('THSarabunNew.woff') %>');
}
```

Everything works fine in the development environment.

But when I want to use it in production environment. I decided to use passenger with Apache2, I want the app to be located at `http://localhost/rails-app` When I precompile the assets with this command:

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile
```

I got the `application-<hash>.css` like this:

```
@font-face{
  font-family:'thsarabun';
  src:url('/assets/THSarabunNew-<hash>.woff');
}
```

which URL is wrong, instead, it should be `/rails-app/assets/THSarabunNew-<hash>.woff`.

How can I fix this?

Regards, Sarun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run your Rails app from a subdirectory you need to change the config.

If it is just on localhost that you want this put the following in `config/environments/production.rb`:

```
YourAppName::Application.configure do
  ...
  config.action_controller.relative_url_root = '/rails-app'
end
```

See if that works for you.

Comment: Thanks, nearly works. I got the URL: `rails-app/assets/THSarabunNew-<hash>.woff`, just missing the first forward slash ;)

Comment: OK, never mind that, now I got it right. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the asset prefix value in `config/production.rb`. The default is '/assets'. So in your case it would be:

```
config.assets.prefix = "/rails-app/assets"
```

Comment: I've also tried that but without success, actually it get worse as all assets are moved.